# Django: Jquery doesn't work suddenly even though nothing changed.. ..is not defined

Tags: jquery, django

Jquery stopped working suddenly today even though I didn't change anything.
I thought js file cannot be loaded from AWS S3 correctly and moved the part to html file but still doesn't work.

here is my `html`

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-warning" onclick="deleteEntry(this)" data-id="{{ entry.pk }}">Delete</button>
...
<script>
var csrf_token = '{{ csrf_token }}'

function deleteEntry(this) {

    if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")) {
        var $this = $(this)

        $this.closest('tr').remove()

        var id = $this.data('id')
        $.ajax({
            url:'/feeds/delete/' + id,
            method: 'DELETE',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRFToken', csrf_token)
            },
        })
    }
}
</script>
```

> SCRIPT1048: SCRIPT1048: The use of a keyword for an identifier is invalid
>   my_feeds (339,22)
>   SCRIPT5009: SCRIPT5009: 'deleteEntry' is not defined

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> function deleteEntry(this) {
>       }

`this` is a javascript keyword.Here, you've used it as the name of the formal parameter in the receiving function. Try changing it to something else, like

```
function deleteEntry(obj){
$this = $(obj)
.........
    }
```